# Shell-based (Terminal) methods for viewing or tailing Windows logs (events)?

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, shell, windows-terminal

I would like to "tail" Windows system logs and other such logs via a shell (in Terminal) in Windows. I don't want to use traditional window log viewing methods such as `Event Viewer` or even other tools that are not shell-based.

Ultimately my goal is to use such a function with MSYS2 or WSL2 to facilitate more shell-based filtering (`grep`, etc.) options.

Are there any methods that make this available?

Comment: take a look at the parameters of `Get-Content` ... especially >>> `Get-Help Get-Content -Parameter tail` <<<

Comment: I doubt that tail will help you here, you need to write your own for this. You will need to use the .net `EventLog` class and setup a delegate for the `EntryWritten` event.  `EntryWritten` will be your "tail".  Take a look at [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/2116c759-6b1c-4442-8d7e-18c54c6f905a/event-based-event-log-monitoring-powershell-script?forum=ITCG).  Also, this might make performance totally suck.

Answer (score 0):

You could install WSL (version 1 for this use case, because it speaks to native Windows filesystems faster than version 2).

This will give you a Linux shell, inside of which your C drive is mounted at /mnt/c.  Then you can do all the good stuff like "tail -f", grep, awk, etc.  I use it for this kind of stuff all the time.  File management, too.  It's very useful if you know a bit of bash or csh.

Comment: Yeah, this would be a really nice option (and I'd go for this) if I could figure out WHERE such logs are stored on the filesystem. Obviously I'd like to transform them into a bit of a different output, which can be done via scripting or maybe a V script (vlang.io), but crap, where's the file path for this/these?